Simplifying Gauss’s Lemma
Hello Math StackExchange Community,
I am revisiting Gauss's Lemma in my lecture notes and considering a simplification in its proof. I am proposing to remove the necessity of proving that $\lambda$ is a unit and would like your input on whether this adjustment preserves the proof's correctness. Here is the complete proof with my proposed modification:
Theorem 8.6 (Gauss's Lemma): Suppose that $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. Then $f$ is non-constant and irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ if and only if $f$ is primitive and irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.
Original Proof:
Suppose $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. It follows that $f$ is primitive because if a prime $p$ divided all coefficients of $f$, then $p \mid f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, which contradicts the irreducibility of $f$ since $p \nmid f$.
Now, suppose $f = g \cdot h$ for $g, h$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}^*$ be minimal (or non-minimal is OK, in the modified proof) such that there is $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $\lambda q^{-1} g$ and $qh$ both in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.
Suppose $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is prime with $p \mid \lambda$. Then $p \mid \lambda f = (\lambda q^{-1} g)(qh)$, we have $p \mid \lambda q^{-1} g$ or $p \mid qh$ (both in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$). The former contradicts the minimality of $\lambda$ directly, and the latter implies $(q / p)h \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $(\lambda / p)(q / p)^{-1} g = \lambda q^{-1} g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. We conclude that $\lambda$ has no prime factors and hence (since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD) is a unit. —> I propose to delete this part.
Proposed Simplification:
“We know that $\lambda q^{-1} g \mid f \lambda$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, since $f \lambda = (qh) \lambda q^{-1} g$, and $qh$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is an integral domain, by cancellation of non-zero elements $\lambda q^{-1} g \mid f \lambda$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ implies $q^{-1} g \mid f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.”
Thus, $q^{-1} g \mid f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and so by the irreducibility of $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, we conclude either $q^{-1} g \sim 1$ or $q^{-1} g \sim f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Hence either $g \sim 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ or $g \sim f$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, and since $f$ is non-constant, $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.
Conversely, if $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is primitive and irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, it remains non-constant. Suppose $g \mid f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, by irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, either $g \sim 1$ or $g \sim f$, confirming $f$ as irreducible and non-constant in both domains.
Would this proposed simplification still maintain the integrity of Gauss' Lemma's proof, or does the omitted step include crucial implications that I'm overlooking? Thank you for any insights or further explanations you can provide.

Please precisely identify "this part" and its proposed replacement so that the reader can easily distinguish them from text of the original proof.

The second sentence of the given argument is incorrect as written. You are missing a hypothesis.  $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and not primitive.

You go from $\lambda q^{-1}g\mid \lambda f$ to $q^{-1}g\mid f$ "by cancelling". This is invalid, because you do not know whether $q^{-1}g\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

In the "Original proof" section, you are missing the hypothesis that $f$ is nonconstant, not merely irreducible. For example, the polynomial $f(x)=2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but not primitive. The conclusion $p\mid f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a contradiction to irreducibility, it just implies that $f$ and $p$ are associates; and this is not ruled out as currently written, because you failed to specify that $f$ is nonconstant, as stated in the theorem.
Your proposed argument fails in the part in quotation marks. You write:

“We know that $\lambda q^{-1} g \mid f \lambda$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, since $f \lambda = (qh) \lambda q^{-1} g$, and $qh$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is an integral domain, by cancellation of non-zero elements $\lambda q^{-1} g \mid f \lambda$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ implies $q^{-1} g \mid f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.”

Remember that $\lambda$ and $q$ are chosen as follows: $\lambda$ is a positive integer, $q$ is rational number, and $\lambda q^{-1}g$ and $qh$ are both polynomials with integer coefficients ($g$ and $h$ have potentially rational coefficients).
That means that even though $f\lambda = (qh)(\lambda q^{-1}g)$ does imply $f=(qh)(q^{-1} g)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, you do not know if this equation holds in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, for the simple reason that you do not know if $q^{-1} g$ has integer coefficients. You know that $\lambda q^{-1}g$ has integer coefficients, and $\lambda$ is an integer, but the coefficients of $g$ are potentially rationals, and $q^{-1}$ is potentially a non-integer rational. So while it is true that $\lambda q^{-1}g$ divides $\lambda f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, you do not even know if $q^{-1}g\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so you cannot assert that "$q^{-1}g\mid f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$." You must first prove that $q^{-1}g\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, which you have not done.
